# The sum of Infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence of rational numbers, then I would like to know why the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k{\chi_{[a_k-2^{-k-1},a_k+2^{-k-1}\ \ ]}}$$ converges $\mu$-almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$. $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

So, this must mean that the set $$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \:{:}\: \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k{\chi_{[a_k-2^{-k-1},a_k+2^{-k-1}\ \ ]}}(x) = \infty \}$$ has a zero Lebesgue measure. So I suppose that $A$ is either a collection of rational numbers or the empty set, but I do not know how I can see this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've changed all $a_n$s to $a_k$s.  If I made mistakes, please fix them.

Comment: @FengShao Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_k=[a_k-2^{-k-1},a_k+2^{-k-1}]$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$, then $\mu(A_k)=\frac1{2^k}$, and thus $\sum\mu(A_k)<\infty$. By [Broel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma), $\mu(\limsup A_k)=0$, which means 
$$\mu(\{x\in \mathbb R: x \text{ belongs to infinitely many }A_k\})=0.$$
So for almost every $x\in\mathbb R$, the sum 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k{\chi_{[a_k-2^{-k-1},a_k+2^{-k-1}\ ]}}(x)$$
is a finite sum and then converges, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. I can understand this so much better now.

Comment: @James Glad to help:)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would there be any $x$ (not taking the almost everywhere into account) that makes the series diverge? Thanks.

Comment: @James For any $x\in \limsup A_k$, the series $\sum2^k\chi_{A_k}(x)$ diverges since there are infinitely many positive terms which are no less than 2.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I was wondering if the set $\limsup{A_k}$ was non-empty.

Comment: @James Maybe it is empty. I think it is related to the enumeration of $a_n$, i.e. the rational number set. I cannot say that $\limsup A_k$ must be non-empty.